# How to override spring boot health endpoint with custom values?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, consul

I want to override the Spring boot Health endpoint with custom json response.
I tried with `public class MyHealth implements HealthIndicator` but that was return some values wrap with myHealth object

this is actually i got after implementation

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "myHealth": {
    "name": "Integration Service",
    "version": "1.0",
    "_links": {
      "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8083/health"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this is i actually i want as output

```
{
  "name": "Integration Service",
  "version": "1.0",
  "status": "UP",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8083/health"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Override or extend ? What is unwanted in your example ? Where is the code ?

Comment: @Marged i edited the question thanks

Comment: We are still missing the code. What is your intended change ? Add the version ? The name and info should be visible by calling `/info`

Comment: As far as I can judge, this blog post copes with the same topic, doesn't it? http://www.jayway.com/2014/07/22/spring-boot-custom-healthindicator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that I am afraid unless you completely override the `HealthEndpoint`. The whole point of the `/health` endpoint is that it provide you a standard structure so that you can monitor things in a consistent way. If you add a custom `HealthIndicator` it's going to be *nested* as you've seen yourself already.

If you want to completely change the output format, you can create your own endpoint and do whatever you want.